# Can we make sections appear in a different order as they are written in the source file?

Tags: sectioning, sorting

I am reading research papers and am compiling summaries of them in a LaTeX document. For each paper, I write a section containing the title, the name of the authors, their institution(s), the year of publication, a summary, comments, etc.

Is it possible to write the sections in an arbitrary order in the source file, and then sort them according to some criterion (alphabetical order of the authors' names, year, etc.) using a command in the preamble (or something similar)?

Comment: I would abuse biblatex for that. Enter all the information into a `.bib` file and the include it as a bibliography into your file. The bib items can then be formatted to basically whatever layout you have in mind.

Comment: One could achieve that with Lua from LuaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possible approach using [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{preamble-nointerpret.bib}
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#1 #2}"}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#2, #1}"}
@article{quackalot2017,
  title={\sortart{The}{Adventures of Duck and Goose}},
  author={Sir Quackalot},
  institution={Duck University},
  year=2017,
  summary={A well-researched chronicle of some waterfowl activities},
  comments={A really exciting story}
}
@article{parrot2016,
  title={My Friend is a Duck},
  author={Polly Parrot},
  institution={Amazon College},
  year=2016,
  summary={An authorized biography},
  comments={Another really exciting story}
}
@article{parrot2015,
  title={Annotated Duck and Goose Lecture Notes for Students},
  author={Polly Parrot and Dickie Duck},
  institution={Amazon College},
  year=2015,
  summary={Lecture notes for students studying the Duck and Goose
   chronicles},
  comments={Accessible and easy to understand reference notes}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

% Ensure document use of \sortart is provided:
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src=preamble-nointerpret,interpret-preamble=false]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src=\jobname,% data in \jobname.bib
  % convert unknown entry identifiers to something that bib2gls will
  % recognise:
  entry-type-aliases={article=entry},% make @article act like @entry
  % convert unknown fields to keys recognised by glossaries.sty:
  field-aliases={
    title=name,
    summary=description,
    author=user1,
    year=user2,
    comments=user3,
    institution=user4
  },
  % Identify fields formatted using BibTeX name style:
  bibtex-contributor-fields={user1},
  % Name ordered to be used in the document:
  contributor-order=forenames,% forenames first
  selection=all,% select all defined entries
  sort-field=name,% order by name field
  sort=en,% sort according to English alphabet
  type=main,% add primary entries to the 'main' glossary
  % also provide a secondary list sorted numerically by year:
  secondary=integer:user2:byyear
]

\newcommand{\glssummary}{\glsentrydesc}
\newcommand{\glsauthor}{\glsentryuseri}
\newcommand{\glsyear}{\glsentryuserii}
\newcommand{\glscomments}{\glsentryuseriii}
\newcommand{\glsinstitution}{\glsentryuseriv}

% Provide custom glossary style
\newglossarystyle{titlelist}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \glsentryitem{##1}%
   \section[\glsentryname{##1}]{\glossentryname{##1}}%
% Change to fit desired format
   Author: \glsauthor{##1}\par
   Institution: \glsinstitution{##1}\par
   Year of Publication: \glsyear{##1}\par
   Summary: \glssummary{##1}\par
   Comments: \glscomments{##1}\par
  }%
% Don't have sub-entries, but providing style anyway:
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
   \glssubentryitem{##2}%
   \subsection[\glsentryname{##2}]{\glossentryname{##2}}%
% Change to fit desired format
   Author: \glsauthor{##2}\par
   Institution: \glsinstitution{##2}\par
   Year of Publication: \glsyear{##2}\par
   Summary: \glssummary{##2}\par
   Comments: \glscomments{##2}\par
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{titlelist}

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Ordered by Title}

\printunsrtglossary

\chapter{Ordered by Year}

\printunsrtglossary[type=byyear,target=false]

\end{document}
```

If the document is in a file called `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

The custom command `\sortart` is given two definitions. The first is:

```
\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#1 #2}
```

which is used in the document. The second is:

```
\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#2, #1}
```

which is used by `bib2gls` when sorting, which means that the article ("The") is moved to the end of the title so that the first title is ordered by "Adventures of Duck and Goose, The" rather than by "The Adventures of Duck and Goose".

First page (ordered by title):

[image: image of page 1]

Second page (ordered by year):

[image: image of page 2]

To add information about the type of publication, you could use the `category` field. This field expects a label as its value, so values like `research` or `tutorial` or `survey` would be fine.

For additional institutions, it depends how you want them. For example, you could just use BibTeX's naming style and make `institution` a list:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{preamble-nointerpret.bib}
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#1 #2}"}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#2, #1}"}
@article{quackalot2017,
  title={\sortart{The}{Adventures of Duck and Goose}},
  author={Sir Quackalot},
  institution={Duck University},
  year=2017,
  summary={A well-researched chronicle of some waterfowl
activities},
  comments={A really exciting story},
  category={survey}
}
@article{parrot2016,
  title={My Friend is a Duck},
  author={Polly Parrot},
  institution={Amazon College},
  year=2016,
  summary={An authorized biography},
  comments={Another really exciting story},
  category={research}
}
@article{parrot2015,
  title={Annotated Duck and Goose Lecture Notes for Students},
  author={Polly Parrot and Dickie Duck},
  institution={Amazon College and Duck University},
  year=2015,
  summary={Lecture notes for students studying the Duck and Goose
   chronicles},
  comments={Accessible and easy to understand reference notes},
  category={tutorial}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

% Ensure document use of \sortart is provided:
\GlsXtrLoadResources[src=preamble-nointerpret,interpret-preamble=false]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src=\jobname,% data in \jobname.bib
  % convert unknown entry identifiers to something that bib2gls will
  % recognise:
  entry-type-aliases={article=entry},% make @article act like @entry
  % convert unknown fields to keys recognised by glossaries.sty:
  field-aliases={
    title=name,
    summary=description,
    author=user1,
    year=user2,
    comments=user3,
    institution=user4
  },
  % Identify fields formatted using BibTeX name style:
  bibtex-contributor-fields={user1,user4},
  % Name ordered to be used in the document:
  contributor-order=forenames,% forenames first
  selection=all,% select all defined entries
  sort-field=name,% order by name field
  sort=en,% sort according to English alphabet
  type=main,% add primary entries to the 'main' glossary
  % also provide a secondary list sorted numerically by year:
  secondary=integer:user2:byyear
]

\newcommand{\glssummary}{\glsentrydesc}
\newcommand{\glsauthor}{\glsentryuseri}
\newcommand{\glsyear}{\glsentryuserii}
\newcommand{\glscomments}{\glsentryuseriii}
\newcommand{\glsinstitution}{\glsentryuseriv}

% Provide custom glossary style
\newglossarystyle{titlelist}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \glsentryitem{##1}%
   \section[\glsentryname{##1}]{\glossentryname{##1}}%
% Change to fit desired format
   Author: \glsauthor{##1}\par
   Institution: \glsinstitution{##1}\par
   Year of Publication: \glsyear{##1}\par
   Summary: \glssummary{##1}\par
   Type: \glscategory{##1}\par
   Comments: \glscomments{##1}\par
  }%
% Don't have sub-entries, but providing style anyway:
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
   \glssubentryitem{##2}%
   \subsection[\glsentryname{##2}]{\glossentryname{##2}}%
% Change to fit desired format
   Author: \glsauthor{##2}\par
   Institution: \glsinstitution{##2}\par
   Year of Publication: \glsyear{##2}\par
   Type: \glscategory{##2}\par
   Summary: \glssummary{##2}\par
   Comments: \glscomments{##2}\par
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{titlelist}

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Ordered by Title}

\printunsrtglossary

\chapter{Ordered by Year}

\printunsrtglossary[type=byyear,target=false]

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page 1]

It's more complicated if you need to associate an author with the corresponding institution. I'm not sure of the best syntax for that, although a cross-reference method may be best. So each author is defined and the article has a field to reference them by label. For example:

```
@index{polly.parrot,
   name={Polly Parrot},
   institution={amazon.college},
   category={author}
}

@index{dickie.duck,
   name={Dickie Duck},
   institution={duck.university},
   category={author}
}

@index{amazon.college,
   name={Amazon College},
   category={institution}
}

@index{duck.university,
   name={Duck University},
   category={institution}
}

@article{parrot2015,
  title = {Annotated Duck and Goose Lecture Notes for Students},
  author = {polly.parrot,duckie.duck},
  Annotated Duck and Goose Lecture Notes for Students
}
```

It's trickier to sort by author in this case. You could possibly adapt the [`sample-authors.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-authors.pdf) example described in the [`bib2gls` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/bib2gls/bib2gls.pdf), which links authors and their publications through a hierarchical method. The entries there are in the form ([`people.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples/people.bib)):

```
@entry{dickens,
  name={\sortname{Charles}{Dickens}},
  text={Dickens},
  description={English writer and social critic},
  born={7~February 1812 AD},
  died={9~June 1870 AD},
  identifier={person}
}
```

and ([`books.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples/books.bib)):

```
@entry{ataleoftwocities,
  name={\sortart{A}{Tale of Two Cities}},
  description={novel by Charles Dickens},
  identifier={book},
  author={\sortmediacreator{Charles}{Dickens}},
  year={1859}
}

@entry{bleakhouse,
  name={Bleak House},
  description={novel by Charles Dickens},
  identifier={book},
  author={\sortmediacreator{Charles}{Dickens}},
  year={1852}
}
```

The custom commands are defined in [`no-interpret-preamble.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples/no-interpret-preamble.bib):

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortname}[2]{#1 #2}
\providecommand{\sortvonname}[3]{#1 #2 #3}
\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#1 #2}
\providecommand{\sortmediacreator}[2]{#1 #2}"}
```

and [`interpret-preamble2.bib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples/interpret-preamble2.bib)

```
@preamble{"\providecommand{\sortname}[2]{#2, #1}
\providecommand{\sortvonname}[3]{#2 #3, #1}
\providecommand{\sortart}[2]{#2}
\renewcommand{\sortmediacreator}[2]{\MakeLowercase{#2}}"}
```

This allows a bit of trickery that can convert the name

```
author={\sortmediacreator{Charles}{Dickens}}
```

into the label

```
author={dickens}
```

allowing the field to be converted into a cross-reference. The complete code for [`sample-authors.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/bib2gls/examples/sample-authors.tex) is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
nostyles,% don't load default styles
stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex and patch styles
style=bookindex]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src=no-interpret-preamble,
  interpret-preamble=false
]

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={interpret-preamble2,people,books},
  write-preamble=false,
  interpret-label-fields,
  field-aliases={identifier=category,author=parent},
  check-end-punctuation={name},
  replicate-fields={name={first}}
]

\newcommand*{\bookfont}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\glssetcategoryattribute{book}{textformat}{bookfont}
\glssetcategoryattribute{book}{glossnamefont}{bookfont}

% requires glossaries-extra v1.23
\renewcommand*{\glsxtrifcustomdiscardperiod}[2]{%
 \GlsXtrIfFieldUndef{nameendpunc}{\glslabel}{#2}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Sample}

\gls{ataleoftwocities}. \gls{bleakhouse}. \gls{thebigsleep}.
\gls{thelonggoodbye}. \gls{redharvest}.
\gls{murderontheorientexpress}. \gls{whydidnttheyaskevans}.
\gls{icecoldinalex}. \gls{thehobbit}. \gls{thelordoftherings}.
\gls{thewonderfulwizardofoz}. \gls{whiskygalore}.
\gls{whereeaglesdare}. \gls{icestationzebra}. \gls{ubik}.
\gls{doandroidsdreamofelectricsheep}. \gls{thetroublewithharry}.
\gls{brightonrock}.

\printunsrtglossary[title={Author and Book List}]

\end{document}
```

This lists by author with their publications as sub-entries. The difference with this example is that there are no co-authors or institutions, but it demonstrates how the author names can be converted to identifying labels.

Comment: This is a very complete answer, thanks a lot! However, would there be a way to include the case where there are many authors from different institutions for a single article? Also, some of the publications are research papers, others are survey papers, some others are tutorials, etc. Would there be a way to keep these categories separate?

Comment: @OpticAl I've added some extra information. For further customisation, I think it would be best to ask a new question (linked back to this) with a MWE that's roughly how you want it and identify the modifications that need to be made.