Re-writing a LaTeX document programatically
Over time, I have written a LaTeX document for some work I'm doing.
Basically, I have a main.tex file that imports each of my little chapters, bibliography, and whatever I have.
Is there a way to, using CLI or some program, reorder sections alphabetically? Like, I started with \section{C}, then I wrote \section{A} and then \section{B}. Can I manipulate the document to reorder them like I see fit, or is copy/paste my only hope? I feel like since the boundaries of the sections are clearly defined it would be easy enough.
The modifications should be in the .tex document itself; this is something i'd want for the writing step and not the publishing one.
Here's some sample .tex document:
\title{Notes}

\section{B}

\subsection{Some B stuff}

\section{A}

\subsection{Some A stuff}

\subsubsection{Some A stuff as well}

I'd expect to be able to reorder it while keeping the hierarchy, if there's a way to do so.
Thanks

Have you considered using an editor with code-folding support for LaTeX?

@WillAdams ah yes, vscode has the handy little arrows to hide parts of the text. it's almost 100% what i want, i'd just need to be able to drag the parts around

I don't know if there is a TeXic to do this, but a simple Python script might do the trick. Just read your .tex file, trim the header / footer, and split the remaining block at each \section command, then sort the resulting blocks according to their first few characters, merge it back together re-adding the \section commands in-between + header /  footer, and voilà! (Your question + this comment + chatGPT + some basic Python skills may give you a working results in no time !)

You can import with some like \input{sectionA} to import sectionA.tex. In this case, you only need a editor able to sort files of text or copy & paste manually (for single lines is still easier  and safer that play  folding-unfolding chunk of text.

@Fran I wanted to have everything in view, splitting it in files sort of splits the mind as well

On the other hand, LyX can do exactly what you are looking for very well, but is not exactly a plain LaTeX editor, so your satisfaction with this solution may vary.

This question is similar to: Sort sections according to alphabetical order. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Marijn sorry, it's for the tex document itself; it's meant to help me reorder my ideas as i'm writing

Some related questions that may be useful as well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411152/can-we-make-sections-appear-in-a-different-order-as-they-are-written-in-the-sour, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51986/89417 (note that the question is about ConTeXt and not LaTeX, but the linked answer is about LaTeX).

@Orsu ah I see, I assumed it was about the output. In that case a different approach is needed.

I'm not sure about VSCode but many editors that support code folding also support selecting folded parts and copy-pasting or dragging around. One example of an editor that can do this is Geany for which I just tested this functionality to ensure that it indeed works.

Not very efficient, but you could do this with a shell script and some temporary files: cut the file into pieces, sort the pieces and reassemble. Slightly more complex if you want to sort within sections, too, but straightforward enough.

Case I (using \input)

in the same directory we create a folder of the “section” type
in the “sections” folder, create as many .tex subfiles as you need.
put \input{C:/Path/to/the/folder/section_1.tex} in main.tex

It should look like this:

The source code of the book is here, check for more detailed example.
Case II (using python)
Taking into account your bio, it says "Full Stack Developper", it wont be a problem to write a small script that reads your LaTeX file, identifies the sections, and sorts them alphabetically while preserving the subsections and subsubsections hierarchy :)

I think i'll end up adding something to the latex extension i'm using, or maybe write a script for that yeah
